# angular initialise object from constructor less class

Tags: angular, constructor

How would you in typescript initialise object from constructorless class

```
export class C1 {
    prop1: string,
    prop2: string
}
```

and in my other class:

```
const obj = new C1 { prop1: 'aaa', prop2: 'bbb' }; // error on this line ( 'expecting a comma')
```

Also, if I use 'let' instead of 'const' I get a tslint error: identifier obj is never reassigned, use const instead of let. Is this really necessary to use const in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For initializing an object from *constructorless* class, you need to assign values to the properties one by one.

```
const obj = new C1();
obj.prop1 = '1';
obj.prop2 = '2';
```

Actually I don't know why you need to have a *constructerless* class. More, you can have a shortened syntax of your code with constructor like this

```
export class C1 {
    constructor(public prop1: string, public prop2: string) { } 
}
```

and create an object simply using constructor

```
const obj = new C1('aaa', 'bbb');
```